# Complete date ranges for two years

Tags: array, datetime, php5

I have array contents with some date ranges, fetched from the database:

```
$calendar = array
             (
             array
                 (
                 'check_in' => '2015-01-02',
                 'check_out' => '2015-02-28'
             ),
             array
                 (
                 'check_in' => '2015-03-01',
                 'check_out' => '2015-06-01'
             ),
             array
                 (
                 'check_in' => '2015-07-18',
                 'check_out' => '2015-08-23'
             ),
             array
                 (
                 'check_in' => '2015-10-17',
                 'check_out' => '2015-10-31'
             ),
             array
                 (
                 'check_in' => '2016-01-02',
                 'check_out' => '2016-02-27'
             ),
             array
                 (
                 'check_in' => '2016-03-19',
                 'check_out' => '2016-04-30'
             )
         );
```

I want to complete the date ranges for two years from now. This is what I expect:

First, let's assume today is Jan, 26 2015, and then set the date two years from today:

```
$today = new \DateTime('2015-01-26'); //set to 2015-01-26
         $start = $today->format('Y-m-d');
         $today->add(new \DateInterval('P2Y'));
         $end = $today->format('Y-m-d'); //2017-01-26
$expected = array(
array
                 (
               'check_in' => '2015-06-02',
               'check_out' => '2015-07-17'
             ),
             array
                 (
                'check_in' => '2015-08-24',
               'check_out' => '2015-10-16'
             ),
             array
                 (
                'check_in' => '2015-11-01',
             'check_out' => '2016-01-01'
             ),
             array
                 (
               'check_in' => '2016-02-28',
               'check_out' => '2016-03-18'
             ),
             array
                 (
               'check_in' => '2016-05-01',
                'check_out' => $end
             )
);
```

These are functions I created to produce `$expected`:

```
function block_calendar($result, $today = null)
{
    $date = new \DateTime($today);
    $start = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    //set interval for 2 years
    $date->add(new \DateInterval('P2Y'));
    $end = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    $patches = array();

    if (empty($result)) {
        $start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($start)));
        $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($end)));
        $patches[] = patch_dates($start, $end);
    } else {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
            $current = $i;
            $next = $i + 1;

            //start
            if ($current == 0) {
                $start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($start)));
                if (strtotime($start) < strtotime($result[$current]['check_in'])) {
                    $patch = patch_dates($start, $result[$current]['check_in']);
                    if ($patch !== false) {
                        $patches[] = $patch;
                    }
                }
            }
            //middle
            if ($next < count($result)) {
                $patch = patch_dates($result[$current]['check_out'], $result[$next]['check_in']);
                if ($patch !== false) {
                    $patches[] = $patch;
                }
            }
            //end
            if ($next == count($result)) {
                $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($end)));
                $patches[] = patch_dates($result[$current]['check_out'], $end);
            }
        }
    }

    return $patches;
}

function patch_dates($day1, $day2)
{
    $day1 = new \DateTime($day1);
    $day2 = new \DateTime($day2);
    $interval = $day1->diff($day2);

    if ($interval->days > 2) {
        $checkin = $day1->modify('+1 day');
        $checkout = $day2->modify('-1 day');
        $patch = array(
            'check_in' => $checkin->format('Y-m-d'),
            'check_out' => $checkout->format('Y-m-d')
        );
        return $patch;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//usage
$expected = block_calendar($calendar);
print_r($expected);
```

So basically, my functions just get patch between two date ranges by adding one day on current `check_out` and less one day on next `check_in`. For example between 2015-06-01 `($calendar[1][check_out])` and 2015-07-18 `($calendar[2][check_in]` is 2015-06-02 and 2015-07-17 `($expected[0])`.

Did my functions have the correct/right implementation to be used with the "date/datetime", or is there a correct way of doing it?